# How do you dynamically set clientHeight and clientWidth for an HTML5 canvas in angular 8?

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that I dynamically display many boxes on based on information returned from a database. Originally, I manually set the height, width, clientHeight, and clientWidth of the canvas and it worked perfectly. However, I'd like to make it scale dynamically with length. Originally, I had:

```
<canvas class="theCanvas" width="700" height="2000" clientWidth="700" clientHeight="2000" #theCanvas (click)=doClick($event)></canvas>
```

Which compiled and ran fine. However, when I change it to the following, I get an error. CanvasHeight and canvasWidth are public variables inside my ts file:

```
<canvas class="theCanvas" width="{{canvasWidth}}" height="{{canvasHeight}}" clientWidth="{{canvasWidth}}" clientHeight="{{canvasHeight}}" #theCanvas (click)=doClick($event)></canvas>
```

It builds without errors in VSCode but my browser throws 
`Can't bind to 'clientWidth' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'`
as well as the same error for clientHeight. Clearly canvas does have these elements because adding those definitions changed scaling versus when they were absent, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

I am running angular 8.3.6 locally and 8.3.18 globally, which cannot be changed since I am not the one in charge of updating that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The width and clientWidth of a canvas cannot be the same.

`width` - the inner width of the canvas without the paddings

`clientWidth` - the inner content width including the padding but excluding borders

Also this goes for the `height` and `clientHeight`